# how to use IIF in a Razor page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use ASP MVC NET6 (Razor page). how to use IIF?, like the following:

```
<li class="mb-75">
   <span class="fw-bolder me-25">Is Supervisor:</span>
   <span class="badge bg-light-success">(@Model.isSupervisor ? 'YES' : 'NO')</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needs to move `@` outside `()`.Try to use the following code:

```
<span class="badge bg-light-success">@(Model.isSupervisor ? "YES":"NO")</span>
```